# unit-testing functions in module

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

Ok, I'm making a serious stab at learning about unit testing for the first time, I'm using Mocha & Sinon.

So hypothetical dumb module, contains functions `foo` and `bar`.  `Foo` depends on `bar`.

```
(function() {

  var bar = function(callback) {
    if (willOfTheGods) {
      callback('err', null);
    } else
      callback(null, 'hurrah');
  }

  var foo = function() {

    bar(function(err, res) {
      //blah deh blah
    });
  }

  module.exports = {
    bar: bar,
    foo: foo
  }

})();
```

I want to stub `bar` so I can test `foo`.

This seems logical from the Sinon docs ...

```
var myModule = require('../myModule');
sinon.stub(myModule, 'bar')
myModule.bar.callsArgWith(0, ['err', null]);
```

but it only works if I call `bar` in the test itself.

```
myModule.bar(function(err, result){
  console.log('err, result');
});
```

When I call `myModule.foo` it still uses the original 'unstubbed one'.

It seems like creating a stub just creates a new local variable for that 
function rather than stubbing it in the module.

Or am I missing something completely - or just doing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Some research revealed that stubbing like this is only replacing the value of the module.exports property not the underlying function.  So I need to use something like [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) to actually get inside the module.

So now if I drop the Sinon stub and just do:

```
var myModule = rewire('../myModule');

myModule.__set__('bar', function(callback){
  callback('err', null);
});
```

it works ... kind of.  It only works if I remove the self executing function wrapping from myModule, ie remove `(function(){ ... })();`.  My understanding was that was a best-practice ... but maybe only in the browser?  Whole different question there I guess.